# Java Netty - Send result to client as StringEncoder or ObjectEncoder depending on input message?

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I'm new to Netty and so far there is a working client-server which can handle String message with StringEncoder and StringDecoder, e.g:

```
        ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
                       .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                       .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE))
                       .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                                                ch.pipeline().addLast(
                                                    new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.TRACE),
                                                    new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Delimiters.lineDelimiter()),
                                                    new StringEncoder(),
                                                    new StringDecoder(),
                                                    new ReceiveMessageCommunicatorHandler(localNode, inpeerNodeRegistry, outpeerNodeRegistry));
```

The input message is just like this: **excute_this** and server sends back: **ok**.

Now, what I need to do is a server receives a new text message: **get_object**, it should send back to any client (e.g: telnet or java application which uses the plain socket) a serialized object as byte array. Then in this client, it can deserialized this object as Java object.

I've known that **ObjectEncoder()** seems to be the way to do. But, it also serializes the response which should be String to a serialized object while it should do it for some specific messages (e.g: **get_object** only).

How can I tell Netty when it should encode result as StringEncoder and when should encode as Serialized Object as byte array?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to dynamically modify the pipeline. When you receive **get_object** message you can simply remove the `StringEncoder` and add the `ObjectEncoder` in the relevant `ChannelInboundHandler`

```
   ChannelPipeline p = ctx.pipeline();
    if (p.get(StringEncoder.class) != null) {
        p.remove(StringEncoder.class);
    }
    p.addLast(new YourObjectEncoder())
```

Or if you know the name of your encoder you can do a replace:

```
p.replace("encoder", "encoder", new YourObjectEncoder());
```

Comment: I tried like you mentioned (default is ObjectEncoder and change to StringEncoder to test)

            ctx.channel().pipeline().remove(ObjectEncoder.class);
            ctx.channel().pipeline().addLast(new StringEncoder());

But client receives empty instead.

Comment: Make sure you add it in the proper place. I mentioned last because I didn't know where your encoder is. You had better use `pipeline().replace()` method. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion of  [Riyafa Abdul Hameed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3599535/riyafa-abdul-hameed)

It can switch Encoder dynamically as in this code when server received a message and writes response to client.

```
@Override
protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, String message) throws Exception {
    InetSocketAddress address = (InetSocketAddress) ctx.channel().remoteAddress();
    MessageContainer messageContainer = new MessageContainer(message, address);
    log.debug("\n");
    log.debug("Message received: {}", message);

    // Handle received message and write result back to the sender
    Object response = this.handleMessage(messageContainer);
    if (response instanceof String) {
        ctx.channel().pipeline().names();
        ctx.channel().pipeline().remove(ObjectEncoder.class);
        ctx.channel().pipeline().addFirst(new StringEncoder());
    }

    if (response != null) {
        ctx.write(response);
        ctx.flush();
    }
    ctx.close();
}
```